# How do I know the leaf information from the each node in a dendrogram?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am trying to do clustering, so I want to know the leaf information at each node after the clustering.
So far, I am able to plot the dendrogram. Attached is the code and picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rACPA.png)

```
import itertools
lst = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3))
import numpy as np
X=np.array(lst)
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
# generate two clusters: a with 10 points, b with 5:
np.random.seed(1)
#Z = hac.linkage(a, method="single")
Z = linkage(X, 'ward')
# make distances between pairs of children uniform 
# (re-scales the horizontal (distance) axis when plotting)
Z[:,2] = np.arange(Z.shape[0])+1 
def plot_dendrogram(linkage_matrix, **kwargs):
ddata = dendrogram(linkage_matrix, **kwargs)
idx = 0
for i, d, c in zip(ddata['icoord'], ddata['dcoord'], 
                   ddata['color_list']):       
    x = 0.5 * sum(i[1:3])
    y = d[1]
    plt.plot(y, x, 'o', c=c)
    plt.annotate(ddata['leaves'][idx], (x, y), xytext=(10,15), 
textcoords='offset points', va='top', ha='center')
    idx += 1
    print(ddata['leaves'][idx-1])
plot_dendrogram(Z, labels=np.arange(X.shape[0]),
            truncate_mode='level', show_leaf_counts=False, 
            orientation='top')`
```